# options overload error in http post request

Tags: angular, httprequest, angular-httpclient

I have a problem with the options of an http post request, I get the following error:

> 'No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 15 '

Referred to options in the http.post request line. How to solve? Thanks

```
 headersNo = {

  }

...

uploadImage(image, imageN, imageUrl, carId) {

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image, image.name);

    let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('image', image)
    .set('imageN',imageN)
    .set('imageUrl', imageUrl)
    .set('carId', carId);

    let options = {headers:this.headersNo, observe:'events', params:params, reportProgress:true};

    return this.http.post<HttpEvent<any>>(this.host + 'uploadCarImage', formData, options);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the code change

```
uploadImage(image, imageN, imageUrl, carId) {

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', image, image.name);

let params = new HttpParams()
.set('image', image)
.set('imageN',imageN)
.set('imageUrl', imageUrl)
.set('carId', carId);

let options = {headers:this.headersNo, observe:'events' as 'body', params:params, reportProgress:true};

return this.http.post<HttpEvent<any>>(this.host + 'uploadCarImage', formData, options);
```

}

Please note down the change where we added observe:'events' as 'body'

Happy coding